# pagination with next and previous button in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

I have tried to add pagination in CodeIgniter with below code, it comes with 1 2 3 4 5 > in this format. But I need a next and previous button to be added.
Controller:

```
public function chooseBale($program_id = '')
{
    $config                = [];
    $config["base_url"]    = base_url() . "ginner/choosebale/" . $program_id;
    $config["total_rows"]  = $this->GinnerModel->get_count();
    $config["per_page"]    = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $choice                = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"]   = round($choice);
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page          = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['pg_title']   = 'Choose Bale';
    $data['breadcrumb'] = ['Home' => '', 'Sale' => 'nolink', 'New Process' => 'nolink', 'Choose Bale' => 'nolink'];
    $data['left_menu']  = "left-menu-ginner.php";
    $data['program']    = $this->CommonModel->getTableWhere(PROGRAM, 'id =' . $program_id);
    $data['program_id'] = $program_id;
    $data['bale_list']  = $this->GinnerModel->baleList($program_id, $config["per_page"], $page);
    $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('ginner/choose-bale');
    $this->load->view('common/footer');
}
```

I have used below query in model file to get records with limit wise.
Model:

```
public function baleList($program_id, $per_page, $page)
{
    $this->db->select('gp.id, gp.lot_no, SUM(gb.weight) AS weight, SUM(gb.staple) AS staple, SUM(gb.mic) AS mic, SUM(gb.strength) AS strength, SUM(gb.trash) AS trash, gb.color_grade');
    $this->db->from(GIN_BALES . ' gb');
    $this->db->join(GIN_PROCESS . ' gp', 'gp.id=gb.process_id');
    $this->db->where('gb.sold_status', 0);
    $this->db->where('gp.ginner_id', $this->prscr_id);
    $this->db->where('gp.program', $program_id);
    $this->db->group_by('gp.id');
    $this->db->limit($per_page, $page);
    $lot_details = $this->db->get()->result();
    $lot_details = array_column($lot_details, null, "id");
    $prs_id      = "'" . implode("','", array_keys($lot_details)) . "'";
    $bales_list  = [];
    $n           = 0;
    $this->db->select('id,process_id,press_no,weight,staple,mic,strength,trash,color_grade');
    $this->db->from(GIN_BALES);
    $this->db->where('sold_status', 0);
    $this->db->where("process_id IN (" . $prs_id . ")", null, false);
    $bales = $this->db->get()->result();
    foreach ($bales as $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($value->process_id, $lot_details)) {
            $lot_details[$value->process_id]->bales[] = $value;
        }
        $lot_details[$n]->bales = $bales;
        $n++;
    }
    return $lot_details;
}
```

View:

```
<p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
```

I have added this link code under the table in the view page code. The pagination works till 5 sections after that arrow comes to the first page.so I am not able to view 6th page of pagination. Is there any other correction need to do in controller or model file to display pagination in the proper way?

Answer (score 1):

See below code ,

we configure the  pagination links via config library

```
    $this->load->library("pagination");
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "blogs";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->blog->getBlogCount();
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do check offical pagination document:
 https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-previous-link
Here is sample.

```
        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'paging/custom';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total_records;
        $config['per_page'] = $limit_per_page;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

        // custom paging configuration
        $config['num_links'] = 2;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;

        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

        $config['first_link'] = 'First Page';
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<span class="firstlink">';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</span>';

        $config['last_link'] = 'Last Page';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<span class="lastlink">';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</span>';

        $config['next_link'] = 'Next Page';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<span class="nextlink">';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</span>';

        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev Page';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<span class="prevlink">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</span>';

        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="curlink">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</span>';

        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<span class="numlink">';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</span>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        // build paging links
        $params["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```